# How to solve this double summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{mn}}$$ And,
 $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{mn}}$$

Comment: Do you know geometric sums? What is the value of the inner sum?

Comment: The sum diverges, there are infinitely many terms that is one. Perhaps you want to start summing $m$ and $n$ from $1$.

Comment: @W.Morozov you should make a new question (regarding the new question you had about $f(c)=...$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{mn}}\geq \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{mn}}=\lim_{M\to \infty}\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{3^{mn}}\\ =\lim_{M\to \infty}\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=0}^N \left(3^{-m}\right)^n=\lim_{M\to \infty}\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^M\frac{1-(3^{-m})^{N+1}}{1-3^{-m}}=\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^M \frac{1}{1-3^{-m}}\\=\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^M1+\underbrace{\frac{3^{-m}}{1-3^{-m}}}_{\geq 0}\geq \lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^M1=\infty$$

Comment: Small nitpick.  For that second summation on the second line (after evaluating the first limit), shouldn't it start at $m=1$, not $0$?  If $m=0$, doesn't the numerator tend towards $0$ as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: @Mike you are right, I corrected thanks. In facts, as pointed by Engineertryingmath the first inequality already cuts $\infty$ down (the case $m=0$) but I kept the proof as it is for two reasons mainly: 1) it uses important tricks that OP should get to know for other computations of this kind and 2) it shows a slightly stronger statement, namely that even when starting $m$ at $1$ the summation diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$\rightarrow\infty $
Hint: take m=0 and solve the inner sum

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both sums actually start at $1$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{3^{mn}}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{3^m\left(1-\dfrac1{3^m}\right)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{3^m-1}<\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1{2^m}=1$$